# Unable to filter user by uid in firebase. Unable to hide component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

Actually Im trying to hide a 'create' component from react native, limited only to one specific uid. I can handle not creating the element on Firebase, but unable to hide/ filter the button 'add' to the regular users. I do not need an admin system or some complex solution like using custom links. Just need to hide the option (seeing the react component) for the rest of uids.

I´ve filtered the creation with a where query on the DB but cannot filter the view. I leave what I´ve tried, but as a result I received all the logged users.

I hope you can give me an idea. If you need more details let me know.

Thanks in advance.

```
//The use effect for logging the users

useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setUser(user);
        });
    }, []);

//The code where I`m filtering the component to logged users

return (
        <View style={styles.viewBody}>
            <ListTables tables={tables} handleLoadMore={handleLoadMore} isLoading={isLoading} />
            {user && (
                <Icon
                    reverse
                    type="material-community"
                    name="plus"
                    size={24}
                    containerStyle={styles.btnContainer}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('add-spot')}
                />
            )}
        </View>
    );
```

In brief. Where should I better make a condition to filter the user uid?

Comment: You want to hide the button plus ? for an specific uid ?

Comment: Exactly, or better said, I want to show the button plus only to an specific id, as it should be the only one allowed to use it, that is what I want. I cannot find the specific way to do it, or lets say, the proper place to apply it. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

you can add one extra key in your user's table.  then you can check it by value,
like this. you can add a new key I suggest the key name is `allow`. then `allow` is `true` then your add button will be shown. I hope you understand my logic.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.viewBody}>
        <ListTables tables={tables} handleLoadMore={handleLoadMore} isLoading={isLoading} />
        {user && user.allow (
            <Icon
                reverse
                type="material-community"
                name="plus"
                size={24}
                containerStyle={styles.btnContainer}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('add-spot')}
            />
        )}
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Since I´m validating trough the Firebase Authentication I only receive the email and uid. Should I create a kind of new colection? as I'm unable to add new keys, on the default way of authentication with Firebase